# How to stop Windows from displaying .java files as "IntelliJ IDEA Project File"?

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, windows-7

I'm using Windows 7.
I uninstalled IntelliJ.
I also tried to set Notepad++ as default program for opening .java files, but without success.

[image]

Comment: [Related question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/49615/how-do-you-remove-a-default-program-association-for-file-types-in-windows-7).

Comment: I'm not sure if that was different on Win7 but with Win8 or later you can start a program called "default apps" and there is an extended menu below something like "manage apps by file extension".

Comment: Doesnt "file properties\Open with..[Change..]\Always use the selected program..[v]" work?

Comment: @AlexeyR. I tried with Notepad++ but it doesn't show on list after choosing. But I was able to change it to Eclipse by "Default Programs", I guess that this is similar way.

Comment: @Line there is a [Browse..] button allowing you to choose any application you want (if it is not listed in the initial dialog).

Comment: @AlexeyR. I know, but when I want to add Notepad++, it just doesn't appear after confirmation (other apps appears normally).